# Do I need a multinomial logistic mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, multinomial-logit

I'm currently working with longitudinal data of patients. These patients are followed for a couple of years and we are interested in two diseases. These diseases can also occur together, can be cured but can also return. Which model should I use to analyze this? First, I thought maybe using three logistic mixed models (disease 1, disease 2, both diseases together). But maybe it's better to use a multinomial logistic mixed model (with possible categories: no disease, disease 1, disease 2, both diseases together)? But are my random effects then the same for every possible outcome? How can I compare the different trajectories of the possible outcomes then? I'm mostly interested in seeing the difference between them, how they are associated,...

Comment: You are "mostly interested in seeing the difference between them, how they are associated..." What are you referring to when you say *them*?

Comment: The different trajectories of the possible outcomes.